# Spring: Don´t load in lazy mode, but get data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have the next problem with Spring and lazy load. I have the next service method:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<A> getA(Long ano, Long idGt) {
    List<A> datos = ADAO.getHorariosAnoGt(ano, idGt);
    datos.size();
    C c = datos.get(0).getB().getC();
    return datos;
}
```

And the next entities:

```
A:
 B b; *(LAZY)*
 Y y;
B:
 C c; *(LAZY)*
 X x;
C:
 H h;
```

Good, when I do it, I didn't get datos with b and c loaded, but *"datos.get(0).getB().getC();"* return data.

Comment: This has nothing to with spring mvc. spring mvc is the frontend framework, you are asking about the service / persistence layer, which means the appropriate tags are spring and / or spring-orm. Also: What ORM do you use? Hibernate? JPA?

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd I'm using Hibernate.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem - are you saying that `datos.get(0).getB().getC();` is throwing an exception, or that it works but you expected it to throw an exception?

Comment: @DB5 Sorry, for my bad English. It's works and return the values, but this values is not loaded in datos. And I want that values are loaded in datos.

Comment: So, `datos.get(0).getB().getC()` is populated *inside* the routine, but if you do a `datos.get(0).getB().getC()` *outside* of the  routine, you get an exception or null?

Comment: Ok! It's works but I discover that the problem is that the eclipse debugger didn't update the variables.

Answer (score 2):

There are some options you could use

- Use eager loading for specific data types, e.g., `fetchType=FetchType.EAGER`
- Manually initialize collection `Hibernate.initialize(..)`
- Employ [Fetch Profiles](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e3524) to toggle lazy vs eager loading
- Visit the objects of your lazy collections *inside* the transaction (similar to what you did), e.g.,

```
for (A dato : datos) {
    dato.getB().getC();
}
```

Comment: Iterate all values in the collections didn't works in this method, why could be?

Answer (score 1):

Ah think I've got you now. So from outside the `getA()` method you are not able to access the Bs and Cs but would like to be able to, right?

Reason for this is the `@Transactional` annotation which means the transaction (and more importantly the session) get closed once the method completes - so inside the method (and therefore within the same session) it is possible to access the lazy loaded associations (your Bs and Cs) but outside the method it is not possible.

To make the Bs and Cs available you can follow any of the options from @Johan Sjöberg. (if you don't want to permanently change the fetch type option 2 is probably the best) Alternatively within the `ADAO.getHorariosAnoGt(ano, idGt)` method you can dynamically change the fetch mode used: 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-dynamicfetching

i.e. `criteria.setFetchMode("b", FetchMode.EAGER)`